# Tableau bar chart looks different in worksheet vs. dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

Trying to make a cute little dual axis line and bar chart, time is continuous on x axis, value on y axis. For some visual flair (formatting still being worked on) I wanted to make banded columns to show months, which are not calendar months (454 system) and are therefore variable lengths of time.

I got it functionally looking how I wanted to on the worksheet. When dragged to a dashboard, even after a ridiculous amount of resizing, I get these weird lines. When I change the size of it, the lines change places.

Anyone have tips on getting these two graphs to look the same?

[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GltM3.png)

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCEy9.png)

Comment: I have found a workaround for the time being. I changed the mark type to Polygon, which had a similar effect, but caused the shape of the shaded area to be slightly sloped. This bothered me. So instead of having my calculated field use 1s and 0s to determine the area to shade, I used 100s and 0s with a fixed y axis of 0 to 0.1. This made the slope so slight that it looks like a straight line.

Comment: what are the filters used in worksheet and dashboard?